# Should not display the alertview if already another alertview is displaying in iphone

Tags: iphone

On the iPhone, how can I check whether some `UIAlertView` is already being displayed before displaying a `UIAlertView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that there is any built-in method for determining if there are any alerts showing.  The way I have handled this in the past is to keep track of the alert views I'm displaying by assinging them to a property like:

```
UIAlertView *currentAlert;
```

and when they are dismissed, setting:

```
currentAlert = nil;
```

Then you just check if currentAlert == nil before displaying another one.

Clearly there are major drawbacks to this method, including but not limited to:

- it only works with alerts you display and not system ones
- You have to implement the UIAlertViewDelegate
- The "currentAlert" property needs to be in something that all of your viewControllers can access, like the application delegate.

But its the only way I'm aware of.

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
for( UIView* subview in [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.subviews ) {
    if( [subview isKindOfClass:[UIAlertView class]] ) {
        NSLog( @"Alert is showing" );
        break;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that this implementation could break if Apple changes the way alerts are shown.

Comment: Thanks!  I have added this snippet into my refactoring library as the UIWindow category property -(BOOL)isDisplayingAlert   see -  https://github.com/peterdeweese/es_ios_utils  - usage [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.isDisplayingAlert